# PHPmyadmin and csv export

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have this code and I want to say if the Stock is a minus then change to zero.

I can seem to get anything to work. It runs from a PHP file via a cron job.

```
    // open connection to mysql database
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    // fetch mysql table rows
    $sql = "select Name, Stock from LMSTOCK";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $fp = fopen('inventory1.csv', 'w');

         fputcsv($fp, array('SKU', 'QTY in Stock'));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))    
    {
         fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Thanks
Chris

Comment: What have you tried to test the stock value? What errors are you seeing? What isn't working?

Comment: _can seem to get anything_ is very unclear. Tip: `$row['Stock']=max($row['Stock'],0);`

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
// open connection to mysql database
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    // fetch mysql table rows
    $sql = "select Name, Stock from LMSTOCK";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $fp = fopen('inventory1.csv', 'w');

         fputcsv($fp, array('SKU', 'QTY in Stock'));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

    {
         $row['Stock']=max($row['Stock'],0);
         fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```